# Referencing Other Assemblies in Script Component

Tags: ssis

When I run my package that has a script component with a reference to my custom assembly, I get this error message
'Could not load file or assembly..'

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to provide more details here. Your package structure or something relevant. It's hard to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSIS scripts can only reference external assemblies that are installed in the GAC. Here's something to get you started:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315682